# Change parameter for whole selection

Tags: interface

It is common to want to change settings for many selected items at once. For some things, like scaling, it automatically affects everything you have selected. For other things, it only affects the active object. Is there a way to make it affect the entire selection?

For example, if I am changing the settings on some bones, and want to set the entire armature to not inherit rotation, I currently have to select every bone one at a time and do it manually. Is there a way to do it for the entire selection? I know I can write a script for it, but then I need to make a script for every parameter that I may want to change.

Another example would be locking/unlocking rotation/scale/location.

A way to copy parameters from the active object to the rest of the selection after making changes would work too. Rigid bodies can do this for rigid body settings, but is there a way to do it for other settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Alt</kbd> while clicking an option and it will apply that change to all of the selected items (in your case, bones) that have that option.